# Chrome for IOS not opening new window correctly in iframe

Tags: ios, google-chrome

I'm trying to open a link in a new window in Chrome for iOS inside an iframe but Chrome for iOS doesn't open the link in a new window, instead the browser opens the link in the same window and not in a new window. The same for popups. Very strange.

Example:

## test.html

```
<iframe src="iframe.html" width="500" height="250"></iframe>
```

## iframe.html

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
function open_popup()
{
    window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank', '');
}
</SCRIPT>

<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">New window</a><br>
<a href="#" onclick="open_popup();">New popup</a>
```

The links opens in a new window when browsing directly to iframe.html but not when browsing to test.html

Is this by design or is it a bug in Chrome for iOS?
If it is a bug, does anyone know how to report this bug?

(Safari for iOS opens the links in a new window when browsing to test.html)

Answer (score 3):

This is a (known) bug in Chrome for iOS. If you want to report it so you can get notified when it's fixed, [file a bug](http://new.crbug.com/) and pick "iOS issue" from the Template menu.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of filing this bug (again), it is better to vote for the existing issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135498

Comment: I think it's actually this issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135362

Answer (score 1):

As Aaron said, it's a known issue on Chrome for iOS:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135362

You can easily workaround it using window.top.open() inside the iframe, but if you have cross-domain limitations or need to handle the window.opener correctly within the iframe, you'll need another approach*.

*Another approaches can fall into the Popup Blocker issue if they are asynchronous.

Comment: I could not get window.top.open() to work with Chrome for iOS. Chrome for iOS ignores this command.