# target="_blank" links opening 'about:blank' page on iPad Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

Basically as the title says: While using Chrome browser on iPad/iPhone, all links using the _blank target open a new tab, but nothing loads in the new tab, it just stays on the 'about:blank' page.

Initially I thought maybe it was because it was going off-site, and therefore was viewed differently by the browser, perhaps as a pop-up, but even with links tested on the same domain, the target="_blank" links are not working.

For example:

```
<a href="http://linksynergy.walmart.com/link?id=GhMPo3mfXjE&offerid=223073.20926333&type=2&murl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.walmart.com%2Fip%2FLeapFrog-LeapPad2-Explorer-Learning-Tablet-Green%2F20926333%3Fsourceid%3D0100000012230215302434" target="_blank">See it</a>
```

The same link works on all other platforms I have tested: Safari on iPad/iPhone, Safari/Chrome/Firefox/IE on desktop Mac and Windows. The link is clicked, 'about:blank' opens for a milli-second, and then the correct page loads. It is only on mobile Chrome that is not working.

Example page for testing: http://www.timetoplaymag.com/product/4446/leapfrog/leappad2-explorer/

In the "Buy Online" box on the right side in green, these are the links that do not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please do not link to external resources. Add the relevant code to your question. Here's why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: There are close to 1000 errors on the [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/). I'm not sure if any of these are related, but they could be. I suggest you fix the errors, and get in the habit of checking your page with the validator after every change. This will save you time in the long run, you can often get strange behaviour with invalid HTML.

Comment: Oops, thanks...That was just an error in a meta tag causing all those errors, only on that one page. That's been fixed.

Comment: I added inline code, was not aware that was needed, I just provided the link for testing.

Comment: I remember iOS chrome had a problem with target blank in links inside an iframe ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260725/chrome-for-ios-not-opening-new-window-correctly-in-iframe ). Are yours in an iframe? Maybe they didn't fixed correctly.

Comment: I did see that thread. This code is not in an iframe. It is loaded via javascript from another server, however, files hosted on my same server are also experiencing this problem.